# Error when converting XML from a CLOB column to XMLType column

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm trying to convert some XML data coming from a CLOB to a XMLType column.

The XML have some accentuated characters as values (documents are written in french).

Here is what the instruction looks like :

```
insert into mytable (id, xmldata) values (p_id, xmltype(p_xmldata));
```

`p_id` and `p_xmldata` are variables previously extracted from the original table.

I think the french characters prevents XMLType to work correctly. Or maybe malformed XML tags? The problem is, the table holds 3k+ XML documents and only 2 are converted in the XMLType column.

---

**Update:** These are the errors I get when I try a simple:

```
select xmltype(xmldata) from mytable

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 254
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used createxml method and now it works fine

```
insert into mytable (id, xmldata) values (p_id, xmltype.createxml(p_xmldata));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This minor change proved hugely beneficial for me.