# SQL xmltype breaks when where clause added

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run a query in SQL Developer (or SQL*plus) to select a portion of a clob field (clobField). To do this I am first using xmltype and then extract(). However, when I try to subset my first select with a where clase, it breaks.

These two statements run successfully:

```
select ID
    from table
    where ID in ('1','2','3')


select ID, xmltype(clobField) as myXmlField
    from table
```

But this one does not:

```
select ID, xmltype(clobField) as myXmlField
    from table
    where ID in ('1','2','3')
```

The error produced is:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 271
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 - "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

From this I presume that myXmlField is being initialised as the wrong type and being fed something it's not expecting. N.B. there are missing values in clobField. Any pointers would be well received.

=============================== UPDATE ====================================

From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219749/error-when-converting-xml-from-a-clob-column-to-xmltype-column?rq=1) I can make it work by using this code:

```
select ID, xmltype.createXML(clobField) as myXmlField
    from table
    where ID in ('1','2','3')
```

However, this does not solve the mystery of why

```
select ID, xmltype(clobField) as myXmlField
    from table
```

works but not when you add a where clause! I've also now run the statement using SQL*plus to check whether this might be a SQL developer thing. The error still occured

Comment: How many rows does this table have? Are you actually fetching all records, including the records with ID '1', '2' and '3' without the filter?

Comment: Have tried executing 
    `select ID, xmltype(clobField) as myXmlField
        from table`
in sql*plus which I presume /would/ bring back all rows. How can I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was a combination of only executing the first few rows. Ultimately the problem was solved by using the createXML method i.e. `xmltype.createXML(clobField)`.